# When I compile my CUDA code,it said:1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00005ff8_00000000-4_lbm.cpp1.ii"

Tags: cuda

When I compile my CUDA code by command :

> nvcc lbm.cu
>   -I/usr/local/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/CUDALibraries/common/inc -lm

the compiler reported the following error:

```
In file included from lbm.cu:15:
lbm_kernel.h:52:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive
/usr/local/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/CUDALibraries/common/inc/cutil_inline_runtime.h(329): error: identifier "CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED" is undefined

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00005ff8_00000000-4_lbm.cpp1.ii".
```

That's the whole content.
I never saw it at all, during my compile other codes. What can I do ?

Comment: I am sure "it" said much more than just that. Could you please edit your question and add both the compilation command you used and the complete output of the compiler. As it stands, this isn't nearly enough information to help you.

Comment: I have completed the command and output.

Comment: @WaisFan Can we see the code of the kernel?

Comment: The last three lines of the kenel file:" __device__ int ind(int x, int y, int z, int k, int4 dim);
__device__ int ind(int x, int y, int dim_x);
#endif __LBM_KERNEL_H_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an *error* and a *warning*.  The error is almost certainly due to the situation you listed in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234535/identifier-curand-status-double-precision-required-is-undefined):

```
error: identifier "CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED" is undefined
```

If you want to know why you are getting that error, it will be necessary to inspect your code, especially the lines that contain that particular identifier (`CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED`)

This may perhaps be due to the fact that you didn't `#include "curand.h"` in your program, which provides a definition of that particular identifer (enum value).

The warning is due to an unusual construct:

```
__device__ int ind(int x, int y, int z, int k, int4 dim);
__device__ int ind(int x, int y, int dim_x);
#endif _LBM_KERNEL_H
```

That last line should probably be:

```
#endif // _LBM_KERNEL_H
```