# Mistake when compiling under Linux a CUDA code originally developed under Windows

Tags: linux, windows, cuda

The code was developed from Windows system, when I compile my CUDA code in Linux system by command:

```
nvcc lbm.cu -I/usr/local/cuda_sdk/CUDALibraries/common/inc -lm
```

Compiler output is:

```
In file included from lbm.cu:15:
lbm_kernel.h:52:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive
In file included from lbm.cu:15:
lbm_kernel.h:52:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive
/tmp/tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-13_lbm.o: In function "main":
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xce7): undefined reference to "cutCheckCmdLineFlag"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2103): undefined reference to "diff_wz_w(dim3, int, double*, double*, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2143): undefined reference to "double gpu_sum<double>(int, int, int, int, int, double*, double*, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x21ca): undefined reference to "fabs_wz(dim3, int, double*, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x220a): undefined reference to "double gpu_sum<double>(int, int, int, int, int, double*, double*, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x22a3): undefined reference to "cpy(dim3, int, double*, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2320): undefined reference to "lbm_step(dim3, int, int, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x23b5): undefined reference to "lbm_bounce_back_exit_inlet(dim3, int, int, float, float, double*, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x248f): undefined reference to "lbm_bounce_back_hole_wall_1(dim3, int, int, float, float, int, int, int, int, int, int, double*, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2501): undefined reference to "lbm_bounce_back_wall_2(dim3, int, int, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x25a2): undefined reference to "lbm_stream(dim3, int, int, double*, double*)"
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2643): undefined reference to "lbm_den_vel(dim3, int, int, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*)"
/tmp/tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-13_lbm.o: In function "__cutilExit(int, char**)": 
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text._Z11__cutilExitiPPc[__cutilExit(int, char**)]+0x21): undefined reference to "cutCheckCmdLineFlag"
/tmp/tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-13_lbm.o: In function "cutilDeviceInit(int, char**)':    
tmpxft_00001fda_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text._Z15cutilDeviceInitiPPc[cutilDeviceInit(int, char**)]+0x8b): undefined reference to "cutGetCmdLineArgumenti"
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What can I do for my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I compile my CUDA code,it said:1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft\_00005ff8\_00000000-4\_lbm.cpp1.ii"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233656/when-i-compile-my-cuda-code-it-said1-error-detected-in-the-compilation-of-tmp)

Comment: You have asked this *exact* question before. Please don't ask it again.

Comment: You are missing the link with the functions listed in the error messages. Do you have them in separate files? You are just compiling the `lbm.cu` file.

Comment: This question is little different from that question.And I put whole imformation here.

Comment: Yes,I add the file,they almost work.The error imformation change to :

Comment: `/tmp/tmpxft_00006c37_00000000-13_lbm.o: In function `main':tmpxft_00006c37_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xf3a): undefined reference to `cutCheckCmdLineFlag'
/tmp/tmpxft_00006c37_00000000-13_lbm.o: In function `__cutilExit(int, char**)':
tmpxft_00006c37_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text._Z11__cutilExitiPPc[__cutilExit(int, char**)]+0x21): undefined reference to `cutCheckCmdLineFlag'
/tmp/tmpxft_00006c37_00000000-13_lbm.o: In function `cutilDeviceInit(int, char**)':

Comment: tmpxft_00006c37_00000000-1_lbm.cudafe1.cpp:(.text._Z15cutilDeviceInitiPPc[cutilDeviceInit(int, char**)]+0x8b): undefined reference to `cutGetCmdLineArgumenti'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include the library that contains the functions that are still listed as "undefined reference:

```
cutCheckCmdLineFlag
cutGetCmdLineArgument
```

These functions can probably be added to your link process using a modification of your compile command line to something like this:

```
nvcc lbm.cu -I/usr/local/cuda_sdk/CUDALibraries/common/inc -L/usr/local/cuda_sdk/shared/lib -lshrutil -lcutil -lm
```

Anyway, you want to find the libraries `libshrutil.a` or `libshrutil_x86_64.a` and `libcutil.a` or `libcutil_x86_64.a` and you want to link them into your program by specifying the path to these libraries using the `-L` switch and specifying the library name (minus the `lib` in the beginning and the `.a` at the end) using the `-l` switch.